# Get Regex content and other data back at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-web-api

This is how I get the real data from my GetHomeData and it is as expected. But it is so that my ContentText there is some text in it that should Regex with something that I have in the database.

I therefore want to hear how I can get it done and at the same time send the data that I have in my result with over the same to get the Regex content.

So what I want is the result and homeViewModel is thrown into Ok at the same time.

```
[HttpGet("/api/Home")]
    public ActionResult GetHome()
    {
        var result = _homeService.GetHomeData();
        var homeViewModel = _regMatcheText.GetRegMatcheText(result.ContentText);
        return Ok(homeViewModel);
    }
```

**The problem is right now**: That I only get hold of the content, I also want to get hold of the other things that are there.

*So my question goes*: How can I fix it so that the content that is Regex that it is sent back.

Comment: Can you try to write this more clearly? I don't understand what you mean by things like "thrown into Ok" or "send the data with over the same" or even "Regex content".

Comment: What I mean is that HomeViewModel and result it should be thrown back together for Return. Here I believe that the data coming from Result and HomeviewModel should be sent back. However, the data in the result.ContentText should not overwrite what is in HomeViewModel. Does it make more sense? @NetMage

Comment: Not really. I have never heard of "thrown" except for Exceptions in C#. And when you say "sent back" do you mean "returned"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like a `Tuple`. You can use a `Tuple` to return multiple values and access multiple values returned.

Example based on the limited information discerned from the OP.

```
    public Tuple<ActionResult, string> GetHome()
    {
        var result = _homeService.GetHomeData();
        var homeViewModel = _regMatcheText.GetRegMatcheText(result.ContentText);
        var okResult = Ok(homeViewModel);

        return new Tuple<ActionResult, string>(okResult, homeViewModel);
    }


    static void DoGetHome()
    {
        var stuff = GetHome();

        var firstStuff = stuff.Item1;
        var secondStuff = stuff.Item2;
    }
```

This is just a rough example. In order to access the values simple access `stuff.Item1`.

If "homeViewModel" is not of Type `string`, then you will need to substitute the correct Type in the method signature.

Comment: Thanks for help.. This help me more!!